# Biased Coin and Probability

Tags: probability

I am currently trying to understand the probability of an occurrence using a very basic biased coin problem. Assume a coin is biased and P(H) = 1/4 and P(T) = 3/4. Is the probability of tossing it twice and getting TH the same as HT?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is true since the tosses are independent. Both are equal to $\frac 3 4 \frac 1 4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing up my confusion!